# How to count empty translations in .po with grep (or other LSB tool)?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, gettext

I can perform search of empty translations in vim with command like this:

```
/""\n\n
```

But my task is to find number of non-translated strings. Any ideas how to do this with **standard** tools which every linux box should have (no separate packages please).

Here is example of .po file containing 2 translated and 2 non-translated string (long and short variant).

```
msgid "translated string"
msgstr "some translation"

msgid "non-translated string"
msgstr ""

msgid ""
"Some long translated string which starts from new line "
"and can last for few lines"
msgstr ""
"Translation of some long string which starts from new line "
"and lasts for few lines"

msgid ""
"Some long NON-translated string which starts from new line "
"and can last for few lines"
msgstr ""
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '$NF == "msgstr \"\"" { c++ } END { print c }' FS="\n" RS= file
```

Results:

```
2
```

Explanation:

Put `awk` in paragraph mode. Then test the last line in each block. If the last line matches the pattern exactly, count it. Then, at the end of the script, print out the count. If you later decide you want to count the number of translated strings, simply change `==` to `!=`. HTH.

---

From the comments below, to handle empty lines containing whitespace:

You'll need to use a regular expression, like: `RS="\n{2,}|\n([ \t]*\n)+|\n$"` (this could be simplified perhaps). However, it should be noted that the [ability for `RS` to be a regex is a `GNU awk` extension](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_116.html). Other `awk`'s will fail to handle multi-character record separators in some way. Fortunately, the above file format looks fairly rigid, so handling lines containing whitespace shouldn't be necessary.

If faced with separators including whitespace, the quick fix is a call to `sed`:

```
< file sed 's/^ *$//' | awk ...
```

Comment: Tested on two files - seems to work ok. I'll test a little bit more and if there would be no issues you'll get your bounty and my best thanks :)

Comment: Thats a very good solution (took me a while to understand it). But to be 100% sure, is there a way of having `RS` to handle if empty lines have some spaces?

Comment: @244an: Thanks. Yes, but only `gawk` can handle multi-character record separators. SO YMMV. Please see the update above.

Comment: @Steve, can the script be modified to print 0 if no non-translated strings are found? Current version just outputs empty line.

Comment: @SergeyP.akaazure: Yes. Simply change `print c` to `print c ? c : "0"`. That's a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). HTH.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using the available `gettext` tools, instead of trying to parse `.po` files directly:

```
$ msggrep -v -T -e "." test.po 
msgid "non-translated string"
msgstr ""

msgid ""
"Some long NON-translated string which starts from new line and can last for "
"few lines"
msgstr ""
```

The `msggrep` flags are:

- `-v` invert match
- `-T` apply next pattern to `msgstr`
- `-e` search pattern

i.e. show any `msgstr` which does not match `/./`, and is therefore empty.

Since `msggrep` doesn't have `-c`, the count in a one-liner is:

```
 msggrep -v -T -e "." test.po  | grep -c ^msgstr
```

(`msggrep` has been part of the `gettext` package since v0.11, Jan 2002. *LSB Core* aka ISO/IEC 23360-1:2006(E) only mandates the `gettext` and `msgfmt` binaries, but I've yet to see a system without it, so it should hopefully meet your requirements.)

Answer (score 2):

As `awk` (nice) solution is already given, there is 4 *other* ways:

All commands was tested with your sample and a good `.po` file.

#### Using `sed`

```
sed -ne '/msgstr ""/{N;s/\n$//p}' <poFile | wc -l
2
```

Explained: Each time I found `msgstr ""`, I merge next line, than if I could suppress a newline as last character of my string`s/\n$//`, I print them `p`. For finaly count the number of lines.

#### Bash only

Without the use of any binary other than bash:

```
total=0
while read line;do
    if [ "$line" == 'msgstr ""' ] ;then
        read line
        [ -z "$line" ] && ((total++))
      fi
  done <poFile
echo $total
2
```

Explained: Each time I found `msgstr ""`, I read next line, than if empty, I increment my counter.

Other bash way

```
mapfile -t line <poFile
count=0
for ((i=${#line[@]};i--;));do
    [ -z "${line[i]}" ] && [ "${line[i-1]}" == 'msgstr ""' ] && ((count++))
  done
echo $count
2
```

Explained: read the entire `.po` file in one array, than browse array for empty field where previous field contain `msgstr ""`, increment counter, than print.

#### Perl (in command line mode)

```
perl -ne '$t++if/^$/&&$l=~/msgstr\s""\s*$/;$l=$_;END{printf"%d\n",$t}' <poFile
2
```

Explained: Each time I found an empty line **and** previous line (stored in variable `$l`) contain `msgstr ""` then I increment the counter.

#### Dash (not bash!)

```
count=0
while read line ; do
    [ "$line" = "" ] && [ "$prev" = 'msgstr ""' ] && true $((count=count+1))
    prev="$line"
  done <poFile
echo $count
2
```

Based on perl sample, this work on both [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) **and** [dash](/questions/tagged/dash)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try:</strike>

```
grep -c '^""$'
```

it counts the lines where the only content is two ".

**EDIT:**

Following from your comment I see that the above does not meet your needs. To perform a multi-line match you could use GNU grep in the following way:

```
grep -Pzo '^msgstr ""\n\n' en.po | grep -c msgstr
```

This was tested and found to work using GNU grep 2.14. I however do not know if GNU grep is standard enough for you.

Explanation of 1st grep:

`-P` activate the Perl regex extension.

`-z` replace the newline at the end of line with a null, allowing grep to keep track of new lines.

`-o` print 'only-matching', required because `-z` is in use; otherwise we'd print the whole file.

Explanation of 2nd grep:

`-c` count the number of lines matching, in this case *msgstr*. This has to be in a separate `grep` statement as `-c` would return 1 if used with `-z`.

Comment: `msgstr ""` - this is a line for non translated string. And it would not count with such grep invocation.

Comment: grep -Pzo '^msgstr ""\n\n' language/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po | grep -c msgstr
    0

And file contains many string but no translations. Example:
    msgid "User Name"
    msgstr ""

    msgid "Password"
    msgstr ""

    msgid "Forgot Password ?"
    msgstr ""

Comment: Does `grep -Pzo '^msgstr ""\n\n' language/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po` produce any output? If not try and revise the seach string `^msgstr ""\n\n`, starting with removing the requirement for there to be no text before `msgstr` (remove the ^).

Comment: `grep -Pzo '^msgstr ""\n\n' language/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po | grep -c msgstr
0`

And file contains many string but no translations. Example:
`    msgid "User Name"
    msgstr ""

    msgid "Password"
    msgstr ""

    msgid "Forgot Password ?"
    msgstr ""`

Comment: yes, it can produce one-string message that file does contains the string matching to the pattern

Comment: In that case, edit the search string as I suggested, and report back what you've tried. Ideally updating your original post. To truely match the vim string you could use the pattern `'""\n\n'`

Comment: I tried `$ LANG="" grep -Pzo '^msgstr ""\n\n' messages.po`
Binary file messages.po matches`

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -n ^msg your.po | grep -v '""' | uniq -D -f1
```

This looks for lines starting with `msg`, ignores ones that are just empty strings (`""`), and then uses `uniq` to look for duplicate lines (ignoring the `msgid`/`msgstr` field).

Sample output from a CUPS file:

```
$ grep -n ^msg /usr/share/locale/es/cups_es.po | grep -v '""' | uniq -D -f1
3742:msgid "ParamCustominCutInterval"
3743:msgstr "ParamCustominCutInterval"
3745:msgid "ParamCustominTearInterval"
3746:msgstr "ParamCustominTearInterval"
3858:msgid "Quarto"
3859:msgstr "Quarto"
3967:msgid "Stylus Color Series"
3968:msgstr "Stylus Color Series"
3970:msgid "Stylus Photo Series"
3971:msgstr "Stylus Photo Series"
3973:msgid "Super A"
3974:msgstr "Super A"
```